# Adress div in XPath with nested properties inside this div

Tags: xpath, robotframework

we want to automate an web application with Robot framework/SeleniumLibrary. The app contains some tables, which do not have simple unique identifiers like id/name/class... They only can be uniquely identified via a nested property. Here a sample excerpt of the properties window (DevTools)

```
grid: window.<computed>
  > FormSubmitOnlyChanged : true
  > ...
  >  _dataprocessor: dataProcessor
    > autoUpdate: false
    > ...
    > serverProcessor: "/TEST/GridNew/multi?group=getMetaData&name=Sources&editing=true"
    > ...
  > ...
...
```

The Element looks as following:
[image]
* The id parameter contains an dynamic id and can therefore not be used for object identification.

We tried some approaches, e.g.

```
//div[contains(@grid._dataprocessor.serverProcessor, 'group=getMetaData&name=Sources')]
```

or

```
//div[contains(@serverProcessor, 'group=getMetaData&name=Sources')]
```

but none of them did work. Does anybody have an idea how to get an XPath that makes it possible to contain the nested property? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you share a link to the url?

Comment: Unfortunately, sharing the link is not possible, because the application runs on an internal server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developers now managed it to set an id manually to overwrite the generated dynamic ID. Furthermore, after more research, it seems to be not possible to use this property for XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this XPath:

```xml
"//div[contains(., 'group=getMetaData&name=Sources')]"
```

The dot `.` means here **any** attribute containing `group=getMetaData&name=Sources` value.
Also, I see the parent element in the shared picture is hidden. Maybe this causes your problems?

Comment: Thank you for this approach. Unfortunately, the XPath does not work for me. Perhaps it is really caused by the hidden parent. I have to discuss this with a developer.

Comment: In case the element is hidden you can't click it with Selenium. Maybe you need to access some other, visible element?

Comment: I just tried again with following path: //div[@class='objbox' and contains(., 'group=group=getMetaData&name=Sources')]   -  For the second child div in browser. I added it in DevTools, but unfortunately it did not find any items.

Comment: Since I can't see the page you working on I have no way to make a minimal debugging

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below xpath:

```
   //div[starts-with(@id,'cgrid2_')]
```

Comment: The given xpath works, but unfortunately it is not unique, because the page contains 10 tables, all starting with @id='cgrid2_' and following by an dynamic number.

Comment: If the tables in the page are not floating, then use indexes for this xpath.  refer this for more information.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-select-specified-node-within-xpath-node-sets-by-index-with-selenium